# ...спотыкается об Исайеву «алма». Возможно ли такое согласование?

Tags: морфология, согласование, падежи, род

**Старик вспомнил, сколько людей споткнулось и спотыкается об Исайеву «алма».** https://pravoslavie.ru/77251.html

- Можно ли так согласовать: учитывать род, но не учитывать падеж (из-за того, что слово в кавычках или не склоняется?)? Есть какие-нибудь примеры похожие?

Comment: Надо бы пояснить. "Алма" — еврейское слово, переведенное на русский словом *дева*. Речь идет о пророчестве Исайи, в котором говорится что "алма" родит младенца из рода Давида, с которым будет связано избавление еврейского народа.

Comment: @М_Г И плохо переведенное, кстати. Правильно было бы "молодуха". )))  Но поскольку перевод шел через греческий и латінь, где таких изысков отродясь не знали, получилось "непорочная дева". Но дело-то не в этом. Коли слово и по форме, и по содержанию принадлежит к женскому роду, то с чего бы оставлять его несклоняемым?!

Comment: @behemothus, Все верно. Присоединяюсь к Вашим словам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Старик вспомнил, сколько людей споткнулось и спотыкается об Исайеву «алма».*

Нормативно было бы *Старик вспомнил, сколько людей споткнулось и спотыкается об Исайево «алма».* Имеется в виду **слово "алма"**, ведь при согласовании с несклоняемыми словами в кавычках учитывается пропущенное так называемое родовое слово.

Но это художественное произведение, автор воспроизводит ход мыслей старика, поэтому вправе употребить разговорную конструкцию и согласовать прилагательное с несклоняемым существительным по смыслу. Алма - это молодая женщина (именно женщина, а не дева, потому он и споткнулся о такой неверный перевод), слово женского рода, значит, и прилагательное к слову тоже женского рода.

Так что в разговорных конструкциях это возможно.

Comment: ээээ... Слово "алма" по всем признакам склоняется. Поэтому предложенный вариант сомнителен именно для разговорной речи. Или *исаейво ."алма"* или "исаеву "Алму". И еще. Зачем заглавная в притяжательной форме?

Comment: behemothus ,заглавная в притяжательном как раз на месте: с суфф. -ов-, -ев-, -ин- прилагательные пишут с прописной буквы (если это не фразеологизм), это Вы уже придираетесь. А что по всем признакам склоняемое - согласна, но другого объяснения нет. Я не знаю этого автора. Скорее всего, он воспринимает как несклоняемое, потому что это иностранное слово, ему чужое, на русском языке встречается только альма-матер, а это несклоняемое, видимо, ассоциации. Когда современные авторы берутся за религиозную тему - ещё не то бывает.

Comment: Ой... С заглавной - да, это я что-то сгоряча спорол... А вот несклонение никак не могу такое пережить. Ладно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу согласиться с подобным. И тут дело не только в согласовании.

1. В первоисточнике речь идет об библейском пророке по имени Исайя (Исаия), правильной притяжательной формой от него будет "Исайино". От "Исай" было бы "Исаево". Вариант "Исайево" невозможен в принципе, поэтому даже и не воспринимается как образованный от имени собственного.
2. Слово "алма" по всем признакам склоняется. Если уж автор категорически не желает его склонять, то и женский род невозможен. Я вообще не могу вспомнить в русском языке несклоняемых имен нарицательных женского рода на "-а".
3. Кавычки при нормальном согласовании, судя по всему, не нужны.

Мой вариант правки: ***Старик вспомнил, сколько людей споткнулось и спотыкается об Исайину алму***. Или уж, если автор не приемлет склонения, то  ***Старик вспомнил, сколько людей споткнулось и спотыкается об Исайино "алма"***.